# Grid Sencha Ext doesn't load data although the store have

Tags: extjs

I'm new in Sencha and in my project, there have a button when you clicked in it will send the request to the server and show the value that returned back in Json form.
I've check and the store have value but I don't know why the grid panel is empty
here my function to send request and load the data into grid

```
    loadVersion: function(i_chronicle_id){
            Ext.getCmp('documentVersionsPanel').body.update('<i>Loading...<i>');
            var documentVersionStore = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                 storeId:'documentVersion',
                 fields:['documentID', 'documentVersion', 'documentStatus'],
                 proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    actionMethods: 'post',
                    url: 'ajaxAction?action=getDocumentVersion',
                    extraParams: {
                        format: 'json',
                        documentID: documentID,
                    },
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'jsonList'
                    }
                }
            });
Ext.getCmp('documentVersionsPanel').store = documentVersionStore;
Ext.getCmp('documentVersionsPanel').getStore().reload();
```

and the grid panel

```
{
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            title: 'Versions',
            id: 'documentVersionsPanel',
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'documentVersion',
                    id: 'versionColumn',
                    text: 'Version'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'documentStatus',
                    id: 'statusColumn',
                    text: 'Status'
                }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: I answered pretty much the same question on the forums: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?279434-4.2-Dynamically-add-store-to-a-grid

Comment: Thanks Evan so much. It worked :)